# How to group a pandas dataframe(categorical) such that it has multiple rows in a single index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

### What I am working with

I have a dataframe which contains columns like this:

```
 Attacktype                       Country 
-----------------------------------------------
 Assassination                    Mexico            
 Bombing/Explosion                Phillipines            
 Facility/Infrastructure Attack   Mexico            
 Bombing/Explosion                Phillipines            
 Hostage                          Phillipines            
 Facility/Infrastructure Attack   Mexico  
 ...                              ...
```

> **Explaination about the dataset:**
> This dataset is a subset of Global_Terrorism data. The **Country** column represents the country in which attacks were performed, while the **Attacktype** column contains information on HOW those attacks were performed

> You can see the whole dataset for yourselves [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rIRkKzFg5aa5OHF7tsh3_bros3MvpKrK/view?usp=sharing)

### What I want to achieve

I want to achieve TWO things here:

1. *I want to display a table like the following:*

```
     Country          Attacktype                      AttacktypeCount
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
     Mexico           Assassination                    13
                      Bombing/Explosion                27
                      Facility/Infrastructure Attack   17 
                      ...                              ...       
     Phillipines      Assassination                    23              
                      Bombing/Explosion                31
                      Facility/Infrastructure Attack   42
                      ...                              ...  
     ...              ...                              ...
```

The only thing different here is that, **Country** are grouped together, and each **Country** has every single **Attacktype** associated with it. The new column **AttacktypeCount** has frequency of each **Attacktype** with respect to each **Country**.

2. *I want to create a barplot(any visualization library) which can show the table above. Like on the x-axis there are multiple countries and each country has multiple bars representing each attack type.*

##### Did I try to actually do any of these myself before asking here?

I have tried different combinations of groupby sort series dataframe and have exhausted myself. I am beginner in Pandas and I am learning through youtube tutorials how to run this thing.

Comment: #1. Your goal is to have a clear visal, so I recommend `df.sort_values(['Country', 'Attacktype']).set_index('Country')`. with Country sorted and as index, pandas display each country once. #2. For bar chart, you may look at these examples for stacked bar chart and grouped bar chart from https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html and https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html

Comment: P.S. For #1, pandas does not really remove repeated country names, it's just for display. Indeed you probably won't want pandas to remove repeated country names, especially if you want to make bar plot later on.